# How to make an iphone application that should not give user permission to delete itself. Is there any way to do so?

Tags: ios, ipad, user-permissions

I am in an organization which is going to provide ipad installed with our app. On particular ipads to sales staff we want that app should not be deletable from that ipad. Is there any way to do so by programatically in xcode? That app is not going to be on App Store. Please help if anyone has any answers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it from within the code of the app. You can do it only by implementing some [MDM](http://www.apple.com/ipad/business/it-center/deployment-mdm.html) solution.

Comment: Hi wain thanks can you provide me a good link how to implement MDM with iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this from Xcode. But there is another tip: you can activate the **restrictions**. Go under Settings -> General -> Restrictions and disable **"Deleting Apps"**. From now, your app won't be deleted.

Comment: It works on ipad but user can delete your application by iTunes